# How to get the value of a specific tag inside XML

Tags: xml, groovy

I want to get specific value from message wsdl xml like this:

```
<Message name="InvestorAcctStatement">
     <Field name="ExtRef">180120120000331</Field>
     <Field name="SeqNum">000001</Field>
     <Field name="AC">0000000800100007182</Field>
     <Field name="CurCod">IDR </Field>
     <Field name="ValDate">20090703</Field>
     <Field name="OpenBal">87928063.0000</Field>
     <List name="StatLine">
        <Record name="StatLine">
                    <Field name="ExtRef">180120120000331</Field>
                     <Field name="TrxType">N9293</Field>
                     <Field name="DC">C</Field>
                    <Field name="CashVal">10000.0000</Field>
                    <Field name="Description1">0800100007182</Field>
                    <Field name="Description2">959508221001000</Field>
                    <Field name="Description3">324242</Field>
        </Record>
    </List>
    <Field name="CloseBal">87938063.0000</Field>
     <Field name="Notes">DR  0640100002095 KE 0800100007182      </Field>
</Message>
```

How can groovy get specific value from that xml?

I already tried with this code:

```
String dbresponse = '''
<Message name="InvestorAcctStatement">
     <Field name="ExtRef">180120120000331</Field>
     <Field name="SeqNum">000001</Field>
     <Field name="AC">0000000800100007182</Field>
     <Field name="CurCod">IDR </Field>
     <Field name="ValDate">20090703</Field>
     <Field name="OpenBal">87928063.0000</Field>
     <List name="StatLine">
        <Record name="StatLine">
                    <Field name="ExtRef">180120120000331</Field>
                     <Field name="TrxType">N9293</Field>
                     <Field name="DC">C</Field>
                    <Field name="CashVal">10000.0000</Field>
                    <Field name="Description1">DR  0640100002095 KE 0800100007182      </Field>
                    <Field name="Description2">959508221001000                         </Field>
                    <Field name="Description3">                                        </Field>
        </Record>
    </List>
    <Field name="CloseBal">87938063.0000</Field>
     <Field name="Notes">DR  0640100002095 KE 0800100007182      </Field>
</Message>

'''
xml = new XmlParser().parseText(dbresponse)

xml.each { 
    if(it.@name == 'ExtRef') {
        println it
    }
}
```

When I run it, it returns

`Field[attributes={name=ExtRef}; value=[180120120000331]]`

I don't know how to call the specific value, especially like field name `CashVal` on that xml code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609279/how-to-read-and-parse-xml-file-with-groovy

Comment: thanks to your answer, i already tried and updated my question, but still dont get the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to print the values in your code try to modify your loop in this way:

```
xml.each {
    if(it.@name == 'ExtRef') {
        println "Name: ${it.@name}"
        println "Value: ${it.text()}"
    }
}
```

Regarding CashVal, here is very rough implementation:

```
xml.each {
    if (it.@name == 'StatLine') {
        it.'*'.'*'.each {
            if (it.@name == 'CashVal') {
                def cashVal = new BigDecimal(it.text())
                println "cashVal = $cashVal"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just for you to get an idea.

Comment: it worked, thank you @AndrejIstomin, and how i can call the value in the Record tag?

Comment: @Kraken I've just updated the answer.

Comment: @Kraken updated my answer once more, no idea why, I did a double nested loop :) Now it should work ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to extract specific simple strings only, without messing up with XML parsing, you can use a "poor man's" regex solution:

```
String dbresponse = '''
<Message name="InvestorAcctStatement">
     <Field name="ExtRef">180120120000331</Field>
     <Field name="SeqNum">000001</Field>
     <Field name="AC">0000000800100007182</Field>
     <Field name="CurCod">IDR </Field>
     <Field name="ValDate">20090703</Field>
     <Field name="OpenBal">87928063.0000</Field>
     <List name="StatLine">
        <Record name="StatLine">
                    <Field name="ExtRef">180120120000331</Field>
                     <Field name="TrxType">N9293</Field>
                     <Field name="DC">C</Field>
                    <Field name="CashVal">10000.0000</Field>
                    <Field name="Description1">DR  0640100002095 KE 0800100007182      </Field>
                    <Field name="Description2">959508221001000                         </Field>
                    <Field name="Description3">                                        </Field>
        </Record>
    </List>
    <Field name="CloseBal">87938063.0000</Field>
     <Field name="Notes">DR  0640100002095 KE 0800100007182      </Field>
</Message>
'''

def extRefs = ( dbresponse =~ /<Field name="ExtRef">(\d+)<\/Field>/ ).findAll()*.last()

assert extRefs == [
  "180120120000331",
  "180120120000331"
]
```